zsh delete one WORD at the time
I'm aware of backward-kill-word but it doesn't do what I want
hello-world
hello_world
hello/world

All the example above will become empty line after backward-kill-word but I want to end up with hello instead.
Is this possible with zsh?

You'll find several similar Q&As here if you search for select-word-style or $WORDCHARS.

Thank to @stéphane-chazelas for pointing me in right direction I found: modifying the zsh shell word split
# defaults:
echo $WORDCHARS
# with removed -_/
WORDCHARS='*?.[]~=&;!#$%^(){}<>'

I don't know if there are any downside with removing this chars, let me know if you think so.
